When to put "articles" before proper nouns?
I have learned some rules for using articles. I have noticed we can use articles before proper nouns but I am not totally sure. From my understanding, this is the rule for using articles before proper nouns.
the/a/an + Proper Noun + Commomon Noun
Ex:
I work at the Coca-Cola company.
I am learning the English language.
But
Zero article + Proper Noun
Ex:
I work at Coca-Cola.
I am learning English.
Am I wrong? Thanks...

Does this answer your question? Using "The" article before proper noun

I work at Coca-Cola. BUT: I work at the Coca-Cola facility in [some place].

In "I am learning the English language", "English" is an adjective not a noun.

'The Coca-Cola Company' is a proper noun, but a compound one. 'The English language' is a noun phrase.
Note that both end with a common noun:

the Coca-Cola company.
the English language.

The definite article is used in both these examples because they refer to a specific company/language.
If you use only a proper noun only there is no need for an article:

I work for Coca-Cola
I am learning English

You likely know that 'Coca-Cola' is not the full and proper name for the organisation, but when using this common abbreviation there is the assumption that your audience will know the organisation and not require any further detail. This is really no different to when using an individual's personal name. For example, if someone said "I work for John" they are assuming you know exactly who they mean. If you didn't know John, they'd have to create a noun phrase with an article like "a man named John".
